# Why .append() changes the position of an element cloned in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, append

I'm currently trying to clone an element and to position it under (or above) the original one simply adding the styles "position: absolute" and "zIndex -1", but it doesn't work.
I tried to check the position before and after the append: it actually changes without no explanation. I mean that I expect the position to remain the same of the cloned object.

So why .append() changes the position of an element cloned in jquery?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Test</title>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function clicked() {
        var $pulsante_temp = $("#button1").clone();
        $("#div2").html("top: " + $pulsante_temp.position().top + " left: " + $pulsante_temp.position().left);
        $pulsante_temp.css({
            "position" : "absolute",
            "zIndex" : "-1"
        });
        $("#div1").append($pulsante_temp); 

        $("#div2").html($("#div2").html() + " After append: top: " + $pulsante_temp.position().top + " left: " + $pulsante_temp.position().left);

        $pulsante_temp.animate({
            top: "-=10px"
        }, 1000);
    }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <button id="button1" onclick="clicked()" style="z-index: 1;">TEST</button>
   <div id="div1" style="height: 30px;"></div>
   <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you expect the position to be the same? That's not what `position: absolute` means. If you don't explicitly place the absolutely-positioned object via `left:` and `top:` or some other means, it's position will be exactly the same as a non-absolute element at that point in the DOM.

Comment: Note that when you clone an element, its position is *not* copied; the position of an element is something separate from it's role in the structure of the DOM.

Comment: Probably I'm wrong, but I expect the position to be the same because I set "position: absolute" AND "zindex: -1". I mean that I think the element will be positioned as it would in a new document (a different zindex should "create" a different layer, so both elements cannot "collide" on the same space.   However, running the code above you will see that the button, immediatly after been cloned, has the position x0 y0 and after the append it has a different position. So it seems that the position is kept when cloning, but it changes on append.

Comment: That's not what `z-index` does. The `z-index` has nothing to do with positioning on the page; layers do not "fill up" independently, in other words. All that `z-index` does is determine what should show on top of what.

Comment: Ah ok, now it's more clear to me. So appending an element with those two attributes will give it new position and then it will be moved upper or lower than other elements. I will try a different solution then. thanks.